# Oracle SQL - naming the result of a join

Tags: sql, oracle

The following SQL statement works fine in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT info.*
FROM (pc NATURAL JOIN product) info;
```

However, running the same statement on an identical database in Oracle fails with the error "SQL command not properly ended."

What is the proper way to name the result of a join in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle you can name subqueries, but not joins:

```
SELECT info.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM pc NATURAL JOIN product) info;
```